# Why drawer icon not white?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-coordinatorlayout

My app contain drawer and any different fragments. Fragments set toolbar for Activity. Why drawer icon not white? I am using white theme for any app. But if call syncState from Fragment drawer icon is black.  When i move toolbar to activity layout it's all fine. Why?

Sorry for my English.

[image]

**Activity layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/app_nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Fragment layout:**

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/flipper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    layout="@layout/layout_please_wait"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addAds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/pager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="sakh.com.utils.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/layout_no_internet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

**Fragment code:**

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getDrawerToggle().syncState();
    .........
    .........
}
```

Comment: try this app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"

Answer (score 0):

Your `AppTheme.AppBarOverlay` should be a child of dark theme

like this:

`<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />`

Comment: Yes it is <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" /> But is not working.

Comment: `AppTheme.AppBarOverlay` has no effect when you put it inside fragment.
`AppBarLayout` must put in activity layout